# MySql sql recursive loop

Tags: mysql, sql, loops, recursion

I am building a navigation menu from a list of pages.
The table is like this:

```
Table name: pages

id | type | parent | name
-------------------------------
1,    1,     null,   root1
2,    1,     null,   root2
3,    2,     2,      home
4,    2,     3,      child
5,    2,     4,      sub_child
6,    3,     5,      sub_sub_child


type:
1 = root page / site
2 = page
3 = ...
```

My problem is that from any page, I have to find the root page.
I have a column **parent** that refers to the parent page, except for the root pages.

I can have multiple root pages in the table, but each page has only one parent.

Could somebody help me to write a recursive query ?

I'm trying to use this query, but it doesn't work:

```
with recursive pages (id, parent) as 
(
    select pages.id, 
    pages.parent, 
    from pages
    where pages.id = 4

union all
    select pages.id, 
    pages.parent,
    from pages
    inner join pages p on p.id = pages.parent
)
select id
from pages;
```

Thanks

Comment: 1. Please post your query. 2. What database are you using?

Comment: AFAIK mysql doesn't support anything like this.

Comment: MySQL's is very limited. They don't have support for recursive queries (or any other modern SQL feature that is). If you need more advanced functionality you might consider upgrading to PostgreSQL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My farovite trick to handle tree structured data in database is add a column `FullID` to table to avoid complex (parhaps recursive) SQLs/Stored Procedures.

```
FullID     id  parent   name
-----------------------------
1          1   null     root1
2          2   null     root2
2.3        3   2        home
2.3.4      4   3        child
2.3.4.5    5   4        sub_child
2.3.4.5.6  6   5        sub_sub_child
```

So, to find the root page id, just extract the first part of `FullID` via SQL or your application language.

If using SQL, you can use the following SQL to get the root id.

```
-- MySQL dialect
select substring_index(FullID,'.',1) as RootID from table;

-- SQL Server dialect
select case charindex('.', FullID) when 0 then FullID else substring(FullID, 1, charindex('.', FullID)-1) end as RootID from table
```

**To delete a node and it's children**

```
DELETE table WHERE id=<CURRENT_NODE_ID> OR FullID LIKE '<CURREN_NODE_FULLID>.%'
```

**To move a node and it's children**

```
-- change the parent of current node:
UPDATE table
SET parent=<NEW_PARENT_ID>
WHERE id=<CURRENT_NODE_ID>

-- update it's FullID and all children's FullID:
UPDATE table
SET FullID=REPLACE(FullID,<CURRENT_NODE_PARENT_FULLID>, <NEW_PARENT_FULLID>)
WHERE (id=<CURRENT_NODE_ID> OR FullID LIKE '<CURRENT_NODE_FULLID>.%')
```

**Note**

This trick is only applied on limited tree level cases, or the `FullID` can't hold long content if tree level is too deep.

Comment: another trick, but sound great. It will be more easy than the easy solution "using php". There is one thing that I don't like... When I move a page, I will have to change all children and subchildren. And at this time, I will have to use a recursive query. So we return to begin of the problem. Thank you anyway ;-)

Comment: To change the parent of a node, you can also use two simple SQLs, 1. change the `parent` of current node: `UPDATE table SET parent=<NEW_PARENT_ID> WHERE id=<CURRENT_NODE_ID>`. 2. update it's `FullID` and all children's `FullID`: `UPDATE table SET FullID=REPLACE(FullID,<CURRENT_NODE_PARENT_FULLID>, <NEW_PARENT_FULLID>) WHERE (FullID LIKE '<CURRENT_NODE_FULLID>.%' OR id=<CURRENT_NODE_ID>)`

Comment: Yes, thanks you. I didn't know the `replace` function. With that, it will be really easy. Thanks You !

Comment: I'd argue that the pattern I've described is slightly more scalable.

Comment: @geekchic, i agree with you, but there's some problems here: (1) the `id` is auto-increment, but the nested set model use **order of visiting** to numbering, so if a node with highest id is the root node, you can't use `id` as **order of visiting**. (2) if using **order of visiting** to numbering, then it will introduce renumbering issue if tree data is modified (node added/deleted/moved), renumbering is expensive as [wikipedia page said](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_set_model#The_technique). (3) as @michael mentioned, he has more than 1 roots

Comment: 1 and 2 are legitimate points, but 3 doesn't matter as each page only has one root. Also, what happens in your scheme once we get to a depth of 11. Then your query of `FullID LIKE '1.%'` will start to return incorrect results, surely?

Comment: @geekchic, what i'm worried in (3) is duplicated **order of visiting number** will occur if there're more than 1 roots/trees. Of course, **this trick is highly limited** the tree depth. generally speaking, `varchar(109)` can handle at least 10 levels if type of `id` is `int`, `varchar(119)` can handle at least 20 levles if type of `id` is `smallint`.

Comment: But you specifically make sure that you don't duplicate the numbers. so one root can have 1,10 say, the other 11,20 and their sub-pages go in between. The only real drawback of the scheme is that inserting becomes much more expensive. However, if you're not doing a lot of alterations to the table, the query speed is very good.

Answer (score 1):

As other posters have commented, there doesn't seem to be support for this in MySQL. You could restructure your table using the [nested set model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_set_model) to get rid of the need for hierarchical queries.

**Example**

Instead of the `parent` column, you have `leftid`, `rightid` and `is_root`.

```
id | type | leftid | rightid | is_root |  name
------------------------------------------------
1,    1,     1,      2         1          root1
2,    1,     3,      12        1          root2
3,    2,     4,      11        0          home
4,    2,     5,      10        0          child
5,    2,     6,      9         0          sub_child
6,    3,     7,      8         0          sub_sub_child
```

Then to find the parents of any given record, you just find the records with `leftid` less than and `rightid` greater than that record. Use the `is_root` column to get the ultimate root record.

Answer (score 0):

The `WITH RECURSIVE` clause that you are using is applicable for PostgreSQL databases, not for MySQL. Oracle has it's `CONNECT BY ... START WITH ...` and it seems, that recursive queries are done differently in every database.

MySQL however, has no support for recursive / hierarchical queries.
You need to procedurally loop through rows to find parents up to the root.

See [how hierarchical queries (like Oracle's `CONNECT BY`) can be emulated in MySQL](http://explainextended.com/2009/03/17/hierarchical-queries-in-mysql/).

Comment: thanks for your answer, that explain why it doesn't work.
And thank you for the link, but I have no idea what I am reading...

Comment: Well, you can do it from Java/PHP/Whatever language you're using, by selecting `parent id` and applying it as `id` in the next it loop iteration until you get `parent id = null`, meaning you got an `id` pointning at the _root element_. Quite inefficient, but working. Or, try to understand what you're reading ;-)

Comment: Yes, I can use php, it will be easy, but I try to to a beautiful code. So i try to use `START WITH`. I don't use often SQL, so it's a little hard to understand what it said, and because english is not my natural language. But I try ;-)

Comment: WITH recursive is ANSI SQL and is not only supported by PostgreSQL but also by Oracle 11.2 (in addition to connect by), Firebird, DB2, SQL Server, Sybase and Teradata.

Answer (score 0):

I think I will add some modification to my database. After talking, I can remove the column **type** and add some table to class the different pages. So the structure is changed. I think I will use a php loop. It's not beautiful, but it work and it's no too slow... there will never be 200 children one under other... But I keep in mind the `START WITH`.

Thank you guys