# SQL recursive loop

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm in a situation quite similar to [MySql sql recursive loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11118537/mysql-sql-recursive-loop), but the answer about adding a FullID column wouldn't be possible for me.

I've a table TREE of elements with a tree hierarchy :

```
ID NAME PARENT
 1    a  null
 2    b  null
 3    c     1
 4    d     3
 5    e     2
 6    f     4
 7    g     3
```

How could I make a query that would return a result like that :

```
a - c - d - f
a - c - g
b - e
```

I tried with WHILE loops, creating queries and temporary tables dynamically, but it ended up being quite complicated and didn't worked.

Comment: "_it ended up being quite complicated and didn't worked._" - Please indicate _what_ you tried and _why_ it didn't work, to avoid reader repeating any mistakes.

Comment: I can't post the code online, but I made a temporary table t0, inserted all the entries without parent in it, and made a loop to create new tables, inserting all the entries where parent=t0.parent (or t(i-1) if i != 0), then another loop to join all the created table together.

Comment: "I can't post the code online"...why not? It's unlikely to be a revolutionary trade secret....especially if it isn't working. If it somehow contains sensitive names or something, then just find/replace them for this purpose.

Comment: Your example of a tree is very particular: *it doesn't fork*. What if `c` had an extra child `g` in addition to `d`?

Comment: `but the answer about adding a FullID column wouldn't be possible for me` why?

Comment: @gotqn I'm not allowed to alter existing tables and can only create temporary tables

Comment: @TheImpaler it's just a small exemple but you're correct, the tree could fork, I'll add that extra line as exemple, thanks

Comment: @Nes Then post the expected result with the forked tree. At this moment it looks like a couple of lists, not a tree.

Comment: @TheImpaler I just did

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a recursive CTE to get all branches. The generic solution looks like:

```
with
b as (
  select id, parent, cast(concat('', name) as varchar(255)) as branch 
  from t 
  where id not in (select parent from t where parent is not null)
union all
  select t.id, t.parent, cast(concat(t.name, ' - ', b.branch) as varchar(255))
  from b
  join t on t.id = b.parent
)
select id, branch from b where parent is null
```

Result:

```
branch       
-------------
a - c - g    
a - c - d - f
b - e
```

For reference, this is the data script I used:

```
create table t (
  id int,
  name varchar(6),
  parent int
);

insert into t (id, name, parent) values 
  (1, 'a', null),
  (2, 'b', null),
  (3, 'c', 1),
  (4, 'd', 3),
  (5, 'e', 2),
  (6, 'f', 4),
  (7, 'g', 3);
```

Comment: While I can find recursive CTE useful from time to time we must keep in mind recursivity in MS SQL is limited and resources hog. Depending on what OP needs he/she can try an XML based solution